# MongoDB group retrieves null in the key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using this to get the result I want, **basically I need the total revenue from each supplier**.

```
db.lineitems.group(
{
    key : {"$partsupp.supplier.suppkey" : 1}, 
    cond : { "shipdate" : {"$gte":19960101,"$lt":19960401}}, 
    reduce : function (curr, result) {
        result.totalgroup+=curr.extendedprice*1-curr.discount;
    }, 
    initial : {totalgroup : 0}
}
)
```

And the result is this:

```
[
    {
    "$partsupp.supplier.suppkey" : null,
    "totalgroup" : 208208820.8400005
    }
]
```

This return the sum of all suppliers revenue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var red2 = function(doc, out) {
out.revenue+=doc.extendedprice*(1-doc.discount);
};

var eachsupp = db.lineitems.group( {
    key : { "partsupp.supplier.suppkey" : true},
    cond : { "shipdate" : {$gte: 19960101, $lt: 19960401}},
    initial: { revenue : 0},
    reduce : red2,
});
```